# Notation of math expressions

Tags: notation

Let $h \in \mathcal{H}$ be a classifier from a hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ trained to infer $\mathcal{y}$ from $\mathcal{x}$, $\mathcal{h} : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow [0,1]^{|\mathcal{Y}|}$. We use $\delta^Y \in \{0,1\}^{|\mathcal{Y}|} : \delta_i^{Y} = \mathbb{1}(Y = y_i),i = 1,...,|\mathcal{Y}|$, to denote the one-hot representation of $\mathcal{Y}$ . Given a loss function$ \mathscr{l}:[0, 1]^{|\mathcal{Y}|} \times [0, 1]^{|\mathcal{Y}|} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ the group-specific risk of classifier $h$ on group $a$ is $r_a(h)=E_{X,Y|A=a}[\mathscr{l}(h(X),\delta^Y)]$.

Can someone explain what the power of a set means in this expression $\mathcal{h} : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow [0,1]^{|\mathcal{Y}|}$ and why it can be used to represent the classifier h and same question for $\delta^Y \in \{0,1\}^{|\mathcal{Y}|} : \delta_i^{Y} = \mathbb{1}(Y = y_i),i = 1,...,|\mathcal{Y}|$ and $ \mathscr{l}:[0, 1]^{|\mathcal{Y}|} \times [0, 1]^{|\mathcal{Y}|} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome. Your title needs a lot of improvement...

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a set and $n$ is a positive integer, then $A^n$ represents the set of $n$-tuples of elements of $A$. For instance, $h: \mathcal{X} \to [0,1]^{|\mathcal{Y}|}$ means that the output of $h$ will be a list of elements of $[0,1]$ of length $|\mathcal{Y}|$.